# remove the signature when creating new appointment meeting in outlook addin js

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

With the help of this method I am able to create a new meeting:

```
Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentFormAsync({
  requiredAttendees: ["bob@contoso.com"] as any,
  optionalAttendees: ["sam@contoso.com"] as any,
  start: new Date(newStartTime),
  end: new Date(newEndTime),
  location: null,
  subject: meetingSchedule.meetingTitle,
  resources: ["projector@contoso.com"],
  body: `https://meet.google.com/${meetingSchedule.caseName}-${meetingSchedule.date}`
});
```

The code for the removing the signature part from the meeting is not working. I have tried more methods like this from the Outlook Office Addin JS.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSignatureAsync("", { coercionType: "html" });
```

This is the part I am trying to remove:

[image]

Comment: That isn't a signature. The details of the Teams meeting are added to the body of the meeting details.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for informing me but is there any way to prevent this ?